# Identify unusual thin component on board that has lost heatsink (marked 'MSE X6')

Tags: identification

**Preamble**

I'm repairing a NOS 1980-something Braun 4262 food processor.

I plugged this in and was immediately met with a great big spark and a puff of smoke. I took the machine apart and discovered a heatsink had fallen off the back of an unidentified component. Of course, of all places, this landed right on top of the board's main contacts, and it has fried itself pretty good.

[image: Fried contacts on Braun mixer]

[image: Fried heatsink on Braun mixer]

**The component in question**

[image: Braun 4262 circuit board]

I found another board for sale on eBay and noticed the component circled on this picture is chunkier than the one on my board. The small strip of metal is also the right length for the thin component on my board, though the white shroud is no where to be found.

Can anyone help identify this component?

It has three pairs of pins (ie, six pins total in three groups of two) and is marked **MSE X6**.

I should add that the mixer did work **briefly** without this heatsink before turning off.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: 'MSE X6 marked' component]

Comment: My first guess would be a specific hybrid IC. Do you know what the whole board does? Is it a power regulator? My second guess is that the board is not dead, the radiator just shorted the mains and tripped the breaker.

Comment: @fraxinus – the regulator is elsewhere in the machine. This board is the speed + motor controller. 

You are correct that the radiator shorted the circuit. With this removed, the mixer will work very briefly, but will then cut out. Whatever this component is, it clearly needs its heatsink.

Comment: Can you take photos from the PCB copper side to understand the component better? As of now it could just be a power resistor that needs heatsink to dissipate the heat.

Comment: @Jack_Luke - Hi, Brief comment that, despite your belief that the heatsink should be attached to the device marked "MSE X6", I am not convinced. The component layouts on your photo and the Ebay photo don't look identical (although it's difficult to compare accurately as they're taken from different angles). However on [your photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9LZP.jpg), there seems too little space for that metal heatsink between the unknown component and the lead of the large cylindrical component (diode?). If I was in your shoes, I would look for other original locations for the heatsink.

Comment: I agree with Jack, it seems like a perfect fit to me @SamGibson  I measure at least 20 pixels to spare in fitting. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS9Ci.png   hmm 3 pairs of pins widely spaced for creepage on a ceramic substrate.  Reminds me of a zener bridge with high R values we once designed for offline supply use using ceramic hybrid design.

Comment: @SamGibson I am certain the heatsink has come from this component. There is a patch of remaining adhesive on the rear side of the component that matches the shape/dimensions of the heatsink.

Comment: @Jack_Luke - Hi, Thanks for the reply. The unknown component seems bent towards the large plastic-enclosed component (motor assembly?) so the heatsink looked like it wouldn't fit in that gap. My concern was that there seemed insufficient space between the metal of the heatsink and the metal lead of the nearby cylindrical component (diode?) on the "visible" side of the unknown component. If there is adhesive not shown or mentioned in the question, and if the heatsink would fit on the "hidden" side of the unknown component, then that explains things. Thanks.